# Error running python script of remote sensing example "Use Planet satellite imagery to calculate change in reservoir water levels"?

Tags: python, remote-sensing, planet

I am trying to finish the following example of 'Calculate change in water level'. I am preparing a .py file to run in from Ubuntu (windows 10) command line. I use the following code

```
import SimpleCV as scv
a = scv.Image("20160707.tif")
b = scv.Image("20160722.tif")

innerA =  a.hueDistance(175)
innerB =  b.hueDistance(171)
innerA.scale(0.4).rotateLeft().save("hue_a.png")
innerB.scale(0.4).rotateLeft().save("hue_b.png")
```

But I receive the following error

```
$ python FindWater.py
ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FindWater.py", line 7, in <module>
    innerA.scale(0.4).rotateLeft().save("hue_a.png")
AttributeError: Image instance has no attribute 'rotateLeft'
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of SimpleCV are you using?

Try (assuming that you are trying to rotate the image 90 degrees counter clockwise):

```
innerA.scale(0.4).rotate(-90, fixed=True).save("hue_a.png")
```

or

```
innerA.rotate(-90, fixed=True, scale=0.4).save("hue_a.png")
```